# Why i am getting this error what needs to be changed?

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from "react";

class cartItem extends React.Component()
  render () {
    return{    
 <div className="cart-item">
 <div className="right-block">
 <div>Phone </div>
 <div> Rs 999 </div>
 <div>Qty : 1  </div>
<div className="cart-item-actions">
  {/* Buttons */}

</div>
</div>;
</div>;

    };
  }
}
export default cartItem;
```

Errors:

```
{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/samar/Desktop/React/shop/src/cartItem.jsx",
    "owner": "eslint",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected \"{\"\n\n  2 |\n  3 | class cartItem extends React.Component()\n> 4 |   render () {\n    |   ^\n  5 |     return{    \n  6 |  <div className=\"cart-item\">\n  7 |  <div className=\"right-block\">",
    "source": "eslint",
    "startLineNumber": 4,
    "startColumn": 3,
    "endLineNumber": 4,
    "endColumn": 3
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of syntax errors in your code.

Firstly you are missing a curly brace at the class definition. It should be

```
class cartItem extends React.Component(){}
```

second , the return should end with paranthesis, not curly braces. It should be

```
return();
```

Third, you dont need semicolons to end HTML tags. Your corrected code should be

```
 class cartItem extends React.Component(){
 render () {
    return(
       <div className="cart-item">
           <div className="right-block">
               <div>Phone </div>
               <div> Rs 999 </div>
               <div>Qty : 1  </div>
               <div className="cart-item-actions">
                  {/* Buttons */}
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   );
  }
}
export default cartItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be just a bunch of incorrect formatting.

1. Braces after React.Component () are unrequired
2. Curly brace return statement instead of ()
3. Missing curly braces {} after React.Component also to encapsulate your entire component.

The error you're getting seems to be from an eslint which is maybe why it's more confusing then it needs to be. Did you check your console for a different error?

```
import React from "react";

class cartItem extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="cart-item" >
                <div className="right-block">
                    <div>Phone </div>
                    <div> Rs 999 </div>
                    <div>Qty : 1  </div>
                    <div className="cart-item-actions">
                        {/* Buttons */}

                    </div>
                </div>;
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default cartItem;
```

:)

Comment: Formatting is important, it might be worth getting a formatter such as prettier or eslint rules for format on save. Will help keep your code clean and maybe help you find some of these issues.